# json data to plist file in document directory , swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to save the json data to plist file in document directory of the application.The code that i have used here is given below. Is there anything wrong that im doing.Thanks in advance.

```
  let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
        .UserDomainMask, true)

    let documentsDirectory = dirPaths[0]
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/flights.plist")
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath) {
         print("File is not present at location")
    } else {
    print("File Already Exist")

        let arrrayOfValues : NSArray = result.valueForKey("list") as! NSArray
         arrrayOfValues.writeToFile(dataPath, atomically: true)

//result.values(“list”) have the values like [{“name” : “nameValue”,”code”: "codeValue"}]
        }
```

Comment: What is `sourcePath`? Also your logic might be the wrong way around: You save the file only if it already exists.

Comment: @MartinR ..i just edited the path..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `-writeToFile:`, because it will write binary data and *plist* file since then will be broken.
You need to use `NSPropertyListSerialization` class to serialize your object to *plist* which is XML with specific formatting requirements.
Aside from documentation on class you can check next documentation section to strengthen your knowledge about *plist* serialization/deserialization: *Creating Property Lists Programmatically*